# My Wordpress domain "page isn't working. [domain] is currently unable to handle this request."

Tags: php, wordpress, http, require-once

When I try to access my domain (qualesce.com for reference) I get a HTTP 500 error message. I recognize this is a PHP problem, but I haven't made any changes to the site since I last went on it (about a week ago).

When I try to go to the WP admin page, I get this error message:

> Warning: require_once(/home/qualesce1/public_html/wp-content/plugins/contact-form-7/includes/mail.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /home/qualesce1/public_html/wp-content/plugins/contact-form-7/settings.php on line 10
>
> Fatal error: require_once(): Failed opening required '/home/qualesce1/public_html/wp-content/plugins/contact-form-7/includes/mail.php' (include_path='.:/usr/lib/php:/usr/local/lib/php') in /home/qualesce1/public_html/wp-content/plugins/contact-form-7/settings.php on line 10"

How do I amend this? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you log in to your wordpress backend?  Can you get to this site via FTP?

Comment: I have a feeling that this is an environment problem...

Answer (score 0):

- Login via FTP
- Navigate to the folder {www-root}/wp-content/plugins
- Rename the folder `contact-form-7` to something else

wp-admin should work now.